# How can I get the functionality of the Scala REPL :type command in my Scala program

Tags: scala

In the REPL there's a command to print the type:

```
scala> val s = "House"
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
scala> val li = typeOf[List[Int]]
scala> :type s
String
scala> :type li
reflect.runtime.universe.Type
```

How can I get this ":type expr" functionality in my Scala program to print types?

Let me clarify the ":type expr" functionality I would like to have, something like this:

```
println(s.colonType)   // String
println(li.colonType)  // reflect.runtime.universe.Type
```

How can I get such a "`colonType`" method in my Scala program outside the REPL (where I don't have the `:type` command available)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implicit conversion should do the trick for you:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit class ColonTypeExtender [T : TypeTag] (x : T) {
  def colonType = typeOf[T].toString
}
```

Comment: This is what I already mentioned. The only difference is the implicit conversion.

Comment: @sschaef It's not. You were getting a name of a type when the question was about getting a name of a type of an instance.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov e.a. Thank you all, the solution works!! I was breaking my brains on this for a week before deciding to ask my first _stackoverflow.com_ question. Next time I will not hesitate so long!

Comment: @user1525911: The next thing you have to do now is to accept this answer to mark it as the one you looked for.

Answer (score 7):

I looked into the sources of the REPL (or better of scalac which contains the REPL) and found this ([Source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoop.scala#L71)):

```
private def replInfo(sym: Symbol) = {
  sym.info match {
    case NullaryMethodType(restpe) if sym.isAccessor => restpe
    case info => info
  }
}
```

Method `info` of `scala.reflect.internal.Symbols.Symbol` returns a `Type` ([Source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Symbols.scala#L1396)). Later `toString` is called on this type, therefore you should do the same if you want the same type information:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>u}

scala> u.typeOf[List[String]].toString
res26: String = scala.List[String]

scala> u.typeOf[Int => String].toString
res27: String = Int => String
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the sources. But I can't figure out how to use that to get a "`colonType`" method (_see clarification edit of my original question_).

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you'd like to achieve?

```
val s = "House"
println(s.getClass.getName)       // java.lang.String
println(s.getClass.getSimpleName) // String
```

Comment: That would be fine for the first example, but not for the second: `println(li.getClass.getName) // _scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$1_ instead of _reflect.runtime.universe.Type_

Comment: I must admit that I don't see the usefulness of your second scenario. I can see that getting the type information ``List[Int]`` could be helpful, but how does the type information ``reflect.runtime.universe.Type`` help you?

Comment: I want to have in a Scala program the same functionality that `:type` provides in the REPL. `:type li` \\ _reflect.runtime.universe.Type_. Therefore, I would like to know how to print this `reflect.runtime.universe.Type` as the ":type" of `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Scala REPL 2.11 :

Add _ after function name to treat it as partially applied function.

Example :

```
scala> def addWithSyntaxSugar(x: Int) = (y:Int) => x + y
addWithSyntaxSugar: (x: Int)Int => Int

scala> addWithSyntaxSugar _
res0: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala>
```