# How to get the type of a function in Scala source

Tags: scala, types

Using Scala REPL, I can get the type of a

```
scala> def tryit(thing: Null): Unit = { println("That worked!"); }
tryit: (thing: Null)Unit
```

Then, how can I get the same information in Scala source outside REPL? 
I tried `getClass`, but I got an error.

```
<console>:12: error: missing arguments for method tryit;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       tryit.getClass
       ^
```

### EDIT

From the other stack overflow question, I could get this code.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486298/how-can-i-get-the-functionality-of-the-scala-repl-type-command-in-my-scala-prog

import reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit class ColonTypeExtender [T : TypeTag] (x : T) {
    def colonType = typeOf[T].toString
}

object Main extends App {
    // Null is a type, and null is a value
    def tryit(thing: Null): Unit = { println("That worked!"); }
    println((tryit _).colonType)
    tryit(null)  
}
```

Running the code will show the result that I expect.

```
Null => Unit
```

Comment: The REPL gives you the type at compile-time, whereas `getClass` gives you the type at runtime. Which one do you want?

Comment: @dcastro: I need to get the compile-time information, but it would be good to know how to get the runtime information also.

Comment: As the error suggests, you need to do this instead `(tryit _).getClass`. This is called eta-expansion, and it converts a *method* to a *function*.

Comment: @dcastro: I get `class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon` from println((tryit _).getClass) which is not that useful.

Comment: Glad that other answer was helpful for you. You can also use `???` if you don't care about actual function body: `def fun(x: Int): Unit = ???`. Same goes for vals and vars